In GTA V, when you stop a car or bring it to a halt, it shifts slightly. Why is that?
When you bring a vehicle to a halt in GTA V it shifts or moves slightly: why does that happen?
It's very annoying, in the sense that it takes away the realistic vibe.
On top of that, I cannot find any discussion about it anywhere.
Please refer this video:




Hard to say without access to the code, and it's still hard to say even with access to it. All I can say is that game physics is hard, and making an accurate physics engine that can run 60 times per second on anything other than a supercomputer is even harder.

In your video, you stopped on a curb. Does the car still shift when you stop on normal road, not touching anything but the road (i.e no curb or anything like that)?

i believe what happens in the game physics when you brake your car back goes up(nollie) what is realistic and when the car goes down again it tries to calculate till what point it should go down. because these calculation might be of because of factors like the car standing on an angle or something else the calculation goes wrong and instead of the car being disformd (body and wheels on two separate places) it corrects the wheels corresponding to the car body. This is only an theory made by logical thinking dont take it to hearth.

Short answer: exiting a car relinquishes control of the car to the algorithm responsible for driving NPC cars, which has lower positional precision for performance reasons.
All cars in GTA not being driven by a player are being driven by "the NPC driver", a single algorithm that runs on each client. If a car is not controlled by the player or the NPC driver, that car does not exist (or it's another object, say, a wreck)
Note that this includes empty cars.
Another point of note is that the NPC driver, for performance reasons, operates on a lower precision level than the player.
From there, it's straightfoward to explain the phenomenon in the video:
When you leave a car, you relinquish control of the car to the NPC driver. Obviously the car is empty, so the NPC driver will not make it move, but since it has lower precision, the car must move to the closest position that is representable using this new lower precision.
The converse does not happen when you get into the car, because the move from lower to higher precision can always be done losslessly.
Working out an example:
the player drives the car to position x=1, y=2, z=3.1415625. They then exit the car.
the control goes to the NPC driver, which will clamp position values to x=1, y=2, z=3.14. The car has moved by 0.0015625 units, and this will be reflected when it will next be drawn on screen.
The actual units and precision levels are different, of course, but this is what's happening.
Source: extensive hacking and modding experience.

But that suggests the car could shift slightly to any position, yet it's usually backwards and to the left. I had the impression it might have to do with the down-force that is applied to it (especially aggressively in GTA V) is being relinquished, since as a car no longer in motion the driving traction doesn't need to be simulated anymore.

As Nolonar said, this is just something to do with the way the game physics have been implemented (and even if the code was open-source, it’d be almost impossible to tell exactly why).

I don't believe this counts as an answer: it's basically saying "because physics", and that information was provided by someone else. This doesn't tell us anything about game engine physics in general, let alone about anything specific to GTA V or the car's behaviour.

@Joachim What do you think a better answer would be?

Something explaining why it occurs, what the physics engine does to result in such behaviour, with a focus on GTA V's engine, preferably with some credible references.

@Daemons I think someone familiar with the game engine, like an experienced modder, would likely have a good understanding of how and why this happens.
